# Use echo inside of a query

Tags: php, sql, echo

I need to include the **value** of an object returned by the linkedIn API on sign-in. When I assign the value of the returned ID to a php variable, I can simply `echo` back the variable which outputs the proper ID. However, when I try to include the variable storing the ID in a query, the query reads the linkedIn JS code literally rather than just retrieving the value.

Ok that probably made no sense at all, so here is an example:

```
$someVar = "<?js= id ?>";
echo $someVar; // Outputs: MD93l2jdJ

$sql = "select * from myTable where my_col = $someVar";
```

In the above query, the server is reading `$someVar` to be `<?js= id ?>` rather than `MD93l2jdJ`

So, is there some way I can use `echo` within the query as in...

```
$sql = "select * from myTable where my_col = echo $someVar";
```

### EDIT

`<?js is LinkedIn Jargin` - see here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this.   Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: What the hell is `<?js=`?

Comment: @DaveRandom I was about to ask the same, have never seen a "js" processing instruction before...

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon: But what content?  In what context does it get replaced with some totally different content (`MD93l2jdJ`)?

Comment: Try using no quotation marks when assigning $someVar

Comment: I suspect the is some very odd Javascript shortcut markup here, and what he actually wants to do is retrieve a client side value and use it in a server side script at page load time, which is obviously not possible.

Comment: @DaveRandom I am fairly positive that linkedIn is returning this value to me server-side.

Comment: @Evan: How?  Is your code running on LinkedIn's server?

Comment: See how here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api

Comment: @Evan: You're aware that Javascript runs on the client, not the server?

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware. However, linkedIn is definitely sending something back to me server-side.

Comment: @Evan: That doesn't make sense.  It can't possibly intercept the execution of your PHP code on your server.

Comment: @Evan: yes, LinkedIn is returning you a value server-side, but that value is _evaluated_ client side. I would agree with DaveRandom's thoughts.

Comment: You assign that literal string to `$somevar`. There is nothign changing that before the query is run. THEN you send it over to wherever you are, and it echoes that string, and THEN it changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this substitution is performed by Javascript, on the client (i.e. the browser).  The value `MD93l2jdJ` never exists on your server.

Comment: I just did some more reading, seems as though I'll need to use the REST API / do an ajax call to get the values server-side.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is going to be a lot more complicated than you are expecting. I suspect that the Linkedin query is executed in the page's javascript, which means that it is client-side. PHP executes on the server-side, long before the client-side code its run.  That means that you can't access this value in the PHP because it has not been populated yet.

Comment: He said he can echo the value...

Comment: Yes, LinkedIn is returning the value server-side.

Comment: @Evan: I don't think it is.  Because that simply doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
$sql = "select * from myTable where my_col =" . $someVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql = "select * from myTable where my_col = '$someVar'";
```

However, you may want to prepare the var before you put it in there like

```
$someVar = mysql_real_escape_string($someVar);
$sql = "select * from myTable where my_col = '$someVar'";
```